# Only show tabs for admins in APEX

Tags: admin, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I was wondering if there was a way in Oracle APEX 5.0 to hide specific tabs from different users. In this case I want to show a certain tab only to the workspace administrators and not to the developers. I already found a way to block certain users out but they can still see the tab and click on it and then they get the error message that they don't have access. If there's anyone out there that can help me out I would appreciate it.

Comment: wouldn't use of an authorization scheme do it?

Comment: Yes, an authorisation scheme assigned to the **tab** - as well as the one already assigned to the **page** (which you should keep)

Comment: Just to reiterate what Tony said, make sure you always also set the authorization scheme on the page as well as the tab, as otherwise they can still access the page by putting the page number in the url.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, it is working just how I wanted it to work.